# Datasource issue on liberty in Spring hibernate Application

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a spring and hibernate application that we are trying to port from Jboss to WAS Liberty profile. When the spring factory gets initialized I am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDatasource': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource [Xlint:cantFindType]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:165)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1441)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) ... 87 more Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource [Xlint:cantFindType]
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ExceptionBasedMessageHandler.handleMessage(ReflectionWorld.java:129)
at org.aspectj.weaver.Lint$Kind.signal(Lint.java:325)
at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.raiseCantFindType(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:232)
at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.getSuperclass(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:98)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.fastMatch(KindedPointcut.java:144)
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.couldMatchJoinPointsInType(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:82)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:236)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:252)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:284)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1598)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:162) ... 92 more
```

My Server has following datasource config

```
 <dataSource id="MyDS" jdbcDriverRef="Oracle" jndiName="jdbc/myDS">
```

The datasource bean on application context is defined as below

```
<bean id="myDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDS" />
    </bean>
```

I would appreciate help. It seems something to do with classloading but I am not able to figure out.

Comment: do you have ojdbc jar in classpath

Comment: try to specify the followings propertiesto you datasource bean definition:ç

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to specify the following properties to your datasource bean definition:

```
<bean id="myDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDS"/>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I did to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The proxyInterface solution worked for me on WAS 8.5.5 Liberty Profile.
On WAS 7, this also works as an alternate solution:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="WASdataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/admt" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.WebSphereDataSourceAdapter">
        <property name="targetDataSource" ref="WASdataSource"/>
</bean>
```